# Get makefile to build two targets from the same file but with different flags

Tags: makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

I'm currently changing a project Makefile in order to build an executable that is exactly the same but passing a different flag to the compiler.

Before changing it, the Makefile was like this:

```
    TARGETS = elilo.efi

    all : check_gcc $(SUBDIRS) $(TARGETS)

    elilo.efi : elilo.so

    elilo.so : $(FILES)
    elilo.o : elilo.c $(ARCH)/sysdeps.h
    ...
    $(SUBDIRS): dummy
        $(MAKE) -C $@
    ...
    include Make.rules
```

Where:

- `$(SUBDIRS)` stores all subdirs of the project
- `$(FILES)`, store all .o files that must be created in order to link elilo.so
- And `check_gcc` just checks the compiler version and exits if needed

Additionally, Make.rules contains general rules to compile and link files:

```
%.efi: %.so 
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .text -j .sdata -j .data -j .dynamic -j .dynsym -j .rel \
           -j .rela -j .reloc --target=$(FORMAT) $*.so $@

%.so: %.o 
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LOADLIBES)

%.o: %.c         # Rule number 1
    $(CC) $(INCDIR) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
# a rule for .S
%.o: %.S 
    $(CC) $(INCDIR) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

**MY TRY:**

So far, I've tried the following in order to have a new target and **be able to compile them both with all rule**

```
TARGETS = elilo.efi usb

all : $(TARGETS)

elilo.efi : check_gcc $(SUBDIRS) elilo.so
        touch $@.touch

elilo.so : $(FILES)

.PHONY : usb
usb : check_gcc $(SUBDIRS)
    CFLAGS += "-DBoot64" $(MAKE) boot64.efi
    touch $@.touch

boot64.efi : elilo.so
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .text -j .sdata -j .data -j .dynamic -j .dynsym -j .rel \
           -j .rela -j .reloc --target=$(FORMAT) $> $@
```

With Make.rules:

```
%.efi: %.so 
    $(OBJCOPY) -j .text -j .sdata -j .data -j .dynamic -j .dynsym -j .rel \
           -j .rela -j .reloc --target=$(FORMAT) $*.so $@

%.so: %.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LOADLIBES)

%.o: %.c usb.touch elilo.touch     # Rule number 1
    $(CC) $(INCDIR) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
...
```

But it doesn't look like the change I've made to the *Rule Number 1* as it now stops when making `$(SUBDIRS)`, probably because that rule is so general that it affects every object file in the project directory and its sub-directories...

Basically, what I want to do **is build boot64.efi just like elilo.efi but passing the flag -DBoot64 to the compiler** so some .c files change its behaviour. Any tips on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've finally arrived to the solution. Instead of modifying the "prototype" rules in Make.rules. I have build a new different path to build bootx64.efi, so it gets build the same way that elilo.efi gets build.

Here comes the code:

```
all : check_gcc $(TARGETS)

######################## NORMAL ELILO ################################

elilo : $(SUBDIRS)
    $(MAKE) elilo.efi
    rm -f $(FILES)

elilo.efi : elilo.so

elilo.so : elilo.o $(FILES)

elilo.o : elilo.c $(ARCH)/sysdeps.h

############################ USB ELILO ###############################
# SUBDIRS must be build using a for, as if not done so, make 
# would take the rule as executed and SUBDIRS wouldn't be compiled 
# with the new flag

usb :
    for dir in $(SUBDIRS); do \
      $(MAKE) -C $$dir CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS) -DBOOTX64"; \
    done
    $(MAKE) bootx64.efi CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS) -DBOOTX64"

bootx64.efi : bootx64.so

bootx64.so : bootx64.o $(FILES)

# bootx64.o is build the same way elilo.o is build (code from the 
# prototype rules has been copied)

bootx64.o : elilo.c $(ARCH)/sysdeps.h
    $(CC) $(INCDIR) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#######################################################################
```

Finally, $(FILES) variable has been modified, taken out elilo.o from it, as elilo.o, 
and bootx64.o are what distinguish .so files. Now this .o files are hardcoded in
each corresponding rule.

Answer (score 1):

I Think you shoud rm elilo.so like this :

```
usb : check_gcc $(SUBDIRS)
    rm elilo.so
    CFLAGS += "-DBoot64" $(MAKE) boot64.efi
    touch $@.touch
```

because if elilo.so is already build without "Boot64" it won't be rebuild

Comment: With the changes I've done so far, it doesn't even get there, it gets stuck doing $(SUBDIRS) (I think it has to do with the dependencies I've added to Rule Number 1)